# Код для расчета электрической цепи

Tags: c++

Помогите написать код для расчета электрической цепи с n-ым колвом резистров, где задается количество параллельных и последовательных связей. Задается число n, и сопротивление каждого резистра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сопротивление параллельной цепи
1/Rp = 1/Rp1 + 1/Rp2 + ...
Сопротивление последовательной цепи
Rs = Rs1 + Rs2 +...

Суммарное сопротивление цепи
R = Rp + Rs

В чем проблема ?